# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection error

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview, rows

hi i am getting this error when running this piece of code and cant figure it out. cheers:

```
      DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= (DataGridView1.Rows.Count); i++)
            {

                if (DataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].ToString().Equals(returnID))
                {
                   SignIn_Time(updateCmd, OLEDB_Connection, varName, varID, varTime);
                   break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
```

Comment: Change "i <= (DataGridView1.Rows.Count)" to "i < (DataGridView1.Rows.Count)"

Comment: In addition to what everyone else is saying, the error message means exactly what it says: `i` is too large.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be less than the count, not equal, because of the zero-based index:

```
i < DataGridView1.Rows.Count
```

Answer (score 6):

The error is clear on what's going on:

> [index] non-negative and **less than** the size of the collection.

Replace `<=` with `<` in the loop header:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (DataGridView1.Rows.Count); i++) {
    ...
}
```

In addition, you need to make sure that each row has at least three cells, because you are accessing the third cell in a row: `Cells[2]`